# Groovy : why this code doesn't work ? unable to resolve class

Tags: groovy

I have this test code:

```
def p = [:]

p.foo = [:]

p.foo.bar = 120

p.foo.bar - 3

(p.foo.bar) + 3
```

why on the last statement i get a compilation error : "unable to resolve class p.foo.bar "?

Thanks for the help

Groovy version 1.8.1

Comment: hmmm, (p.foo[bar]) + 3 works - maybe compiler is confused.

Comment: Wow, that *is weird*.  Oddly, this works: `(p.foo).bar + 3`.  I also tried using classes with defined properties instead, but got the same error!  It looks like putting it in parentheses like that causes it to look for a package called `p.foo` with a class called `bar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I think I figured it out.  I ran the AST browser against your sample script (using the GroovyConsole).  It would only show an output at the *Conversion* phase.  At this phase you can see how the script is converted.  The key is that the last line is converted into this:

```
...
((1) as p.foo.bar)
```

This means that, apparently, it's trying to *cast or convert* the `1` into a class named `p.foo.bar`.

You can dig a little deeper and see that the parser is parsing the statement like this:

```
(p.foo.bar)(+1)
```

Which is the same as

```
(p.foo.bar)1
```

Therefore, the parser/compiler is seeing the `+` as a unary `+` operator.  And that is why you are getting the error.  (The way around it it to remove the parentheses, or swap the order of the arguments!)

Comment: Do you consider this behaviour of the compiler/parser right or like an error/bug?

Comment: Unexpected, maybe, but definitely not a bug.  Wrapping a single class is a standard way to cast.  I don't see how this would ever be written this way normally, either.